# Amazon SNS notification validation when RawMessageDelivery is enabled

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

How do I validate an SNS notification when RawMessageDelivery is true?
It doesn't contain the Signature, the SignatureVersion or the SigningCertURL.

These are all the headers I receive:

```
x-amz-sns-message-type
x-amz-sns-message-id
x-amz-sns-topic-arn
x-amz-sns-subscription-arn
x-amz-sns-rawdelivery
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon replied to me with:

> [...] We basically return everything that you sent over HTTP and nothing
>   else when RawMessageDelivery is turned on.

So if validating the message is a must, this needs to be turned off.